# Regular expression properties (theory)

Tags: regex, theory

I'm reading Aho and Ullman's book The Theory of Parsing, Translation, and Compiling. In the section that introduces regular expressions in chapter 2, there is a list of properties of regular expressions. I do not understand properties 2 and 8. Here is the list of properties:

(1)  +  =  +

(2) ∅* =

(3)  + ( + ) = ( + ) +

(4) () = ()

(5) ( + ) =  +

(6) ( + ) =  +

(7)  =  =

(8) ∅ = ∅ = ∅

(9) * =  + *

(10) (* )* = *

(11)  +  =

(12)  + ∅ =

where ∅ is the regular expression denoting the regular set ∅, , ,  are arbitrary regular expressions, and  is the empty string.

**How are properties (2) and (8) justified?**

Edit: To explain the notation of +, *, etc, here are some definitions given in the book (quoted):

> DEFINITION Let  be a finite alphabet. We define a *regular set over*
>    recursively in the following manner:
>
> (1) ∅ (the empty set) is a regular set over .
>
> (2) {} is a regular set over .
>
> (3) {} is a regular set over  for all  in .
>
> (4) If  and  are regular sets over , then so are
>
> (a)  ∪ .
>
> (b) .
>
> (c) *.
>
> (5) Nothing else is a regular set.
>
> Thus a subset of * is regular if and only if it is ∅, {}, or {},
>   for some  in , or can be obtained from these by a finite number of
>   applications of the operations union, concatenation, and closure.

.

> DEFINITION *Regular expressions* over  and the regular expressions
>   they *denote* are defined recursively, as follows:
>
> (1) ∅ is a regular expression denoting the regular set ∅.
>
> (2)  is a regular expression denoting the regular set {}.
>
> (3)  in  is a regular expression denoting the regular set {}.
>
> (4) If  and  are regular expressions denoting the regular sets 
>   and , respectively, then
>
> (a) (+) is a regular expression denoting  ∪ .
>
> (b) () is a regular expression denoting .
>
> (c) ()* is a regular expression denoting *.
>
> (5) Nothing else is a regular expression.

Comment: Consider checking out [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) and you might find your question is a better fit there.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check those out.

Comment: What do those punctuation char's do `*+()=` ?

Comment: @sin I'll add another edit explaining those

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that 2 & 8 properties might be just a simple math:

#### Property 2

∅ is an empty set, then `∅* =`  is true, `∅+ =`  is also true, `∅{Infinity} =`  is also true, since e is an empty string.

A regular expression is a **string**, thus an empty regular expression repeating any number of times or with any operation, is still an empty regular expression, which again equals to an empty string in the right side.

Reference:
[Why is the Kleene star of a null set is an empty string?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/908192/why-is-the-kleene-star-of-a-null-set-is-an-empty-string)

---

#### Property 8

`∅ = ∅ = ∅` is true, and so is `∅∅∅ = ∅∅∅ = ∅`, because an empty set combined with anything would result an empty set.

---

#### Reference:

[Regular expressions with empty set/empty string](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1503803/regular-expressions-with-empty-set-empty-string)

[What is the difference between language of empty string and empty set language?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1112048/what-is-the-difference-between-language-of-empty-string-and-empty-set-language)

[How can concatenating empty sets (languages) result in a set containing empty string?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/590500/how-can-concatenating-empty-sets-languages-result-in-a-set-containing-empty-st)

Comment: It makes sense now, that reference you edited in really helped. Thank you!

Comment: That's okay, I think I understand it well enough to create a proof of it if I need to. I'll keep Math SO (and CS!) in mind for future questions though. Thanks again!

Comment: @user109923 Tip: Remember to go through the Help Center of each of them (as well as StackOverflow's) so you can decide what questions are more appropriate for which sites. Good luck :)